# Scrollview is not working inside GestureRecognizer React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a flatlist inside of GestureRecognizer. But scrolling of the flatlist is not working because of gestureRecongizer. without this it works perfectly but If I use GestureRecognizer, vertical scroll is getting stuck for my flatlist. How can I fix this problem ?

```
    <GestureRecognizer
      config={{
        velocityThreshold: 0.1,
        directionalOffsetThreshold: 95,
      }}
      style={styles.gestureContainer}
      onSwipe={(direction, state) => onSwipe(direction, state)}>
      <Host>
        <Screen safeAreaColor={whiteColor}>
          <View style={styles.container} behavior={null}>
            <View style={styles.progressBarContainer}>
              <ProgressBar
                progress={progressRef.current}
                width={null}
                color={progressBarFilledBgColor}
                height={moderateScale(6)}
                borderRadius={moderateScale(6)}
                unfilledColor={progressBarUnFilledBgColor}
                borderWidth={0}
              />
            </View>

            <PagerView
              ref={pager}
              style={styles.pagerView}
              initialPage={loginType && loginType == COMMON.APPLE ? 1 : 0}
              scrollEnabled={false}>
              <View key="1">
                <SignupStep1 onNext={onNext} />
              </View>
              <View key="2">
                <SignupStep2 ref={signupStep2Ref} onNext={onNext} />
              </View>
              <View key="3">
                <SignupStep3 ref={signupStep3Ref} onNext={onNext} />
              </View>
              <View key="4">
                 <FlatList
                   contentContainerStyle={styles.hobbyCatListContainer}
                   keyExtractor={item => (isFetching ? item.toString() : 
                   String(item.id))}
                   data={isFetching ? mockData : hobbyCategotyList}
                   ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.seperator} />}
                   renderItem={renderItem}
                   ref={signupStep4Ref} onNext={onNext}
                />
              </View>
            </PagerView>
            <MessageBar navigation={props.navigation} />
          </View>
        </Screen>
      </Host>
    </GestureRecognizer>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with 'GestureRecognizer from react-native-swipe-gestures'...and doing some research on it, I still haven't got a solution

Comment: did you try to implement below code into node modules ? @sahasrabhujaneuron

Comment: I just tried it, and it started working! This is a miracle. However, the scrolling isn't smooth, is it?

Comment: Also, I got this warning  `Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.
* Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.
* Rename componentWillMount to UNSAFE_componentWillMount to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 18.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.`

Comment: hmmm i actually don't remember if i've received this warning myself unfortunately. about the scrolling, my scrolling was smooth from bottom to top which was i needed but it was not quite effective from top to bottom but was acceptable for my case. @sahasrabhujaneuron

Comment: Thanks for the replay! ` but it was not quite effective from top to bottom`...yeah same here. We just wanted to implement a basic feature both swiping left/right and scrolling. That's a common feature for apps, right? So It has to be easy, but there aren't lots of info for that unfortunately. But anyhow, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

if anyone has the same issue, I searched a lot but I could only find one solution that works from Github issues. and it is to disable up and down gestures. in my case, I only needed left swipe. you can change the original codes with the below codes in the `node_modules/react-native-swipe-gestures/index.js` file.

I am still open to new solutions as well if you have ever faced this issue before and had a different solution, please share with me. I would be so appreciated it.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, PanResponder} from 'react-native';

export const swipeDirections = {
  SWIPE_LEFT: 'SWIPE_LEFT',
  SWIPE_RIGHT: 'SWIPE_RIGHT'
};

const swipeConfig = {
  velocityThreshold: 0.3,
  directionalOffsetThreshold: 80
};

function isValidSwipe(velocity, velocityThreshold, directionalOffset, directionalOffsetThreshold) {
  return Math.abs(velocity) > velocityThreshold && Math.abs(directionalOffset) < directionalOffsetThreshold;
}

class GestureRecognizer extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.swipeConfig = Object.assign(swipeConfig, props.config);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.swipeConfig = Object.assign(swipeConfig, props.config);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const responderEnd = this._handlePanResponderEnd.bind(this);
    const shouldSetResponder = this._handleShouldSetPanResponder.bind(this);
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({ //stop JS beautify collapse
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: shouldSetResponder,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: shouldSetResponder,
      onPanResponderRelease: responderEnd,
      onPanResponderTerminate: responderEnd
    });
  }

  _handleShouldSetPanResponder(evt, gestureState) {
    return evt.nativeEvent.touches.length === 1 && !this._gestureIsClick(gestureState);
  }
  
  _gestureIsClick(gestureState) {
    return Math.abs(gestureState.dx) < 5;
  }

  _handlePanResponderEnd(evt, gestureState) {
    const swipeDirection = this._getSwipeDirection(gestureState);
    this._triggerSwipeHandlers(swipeDirection, gestureState);
  }

  _triggerSwipeHandlers(swipeDirection, gestureState) {
    const {onSwipe, onSwipeLeft, onSwipeRight} = this.props;
    const {SWIPE_LEFT, SWIPE_RIGHT,} = swipeDirections;
    onSwipe && onSwipe(swipeDirection, gestureState);
    switch (swipeDirection) {
      case SWIPE_LEFT:
        onSwipeLeft && onSwipeLeft(gestureState);
        break;
      case SWIPE_RIGHT:
        onSwipeRight && onSwipeRight(gestureState);
        break;
    }
  }

  _getSwipeDirection(gestureState) {
    const {SWIPE_LEFT, SWIPE_RIGHT} = swipeDirections;
    const {dx} = gestureState;
    if (this._isValidHorizontalSwipe(gestureState)) {
      return (dx > 0)
        ? SWIPE_RIGHT
        : SWIPE_LEFT;
    } 
    return null;
  }

  _isValidHorizontalSwipe(gestureState) {
    const {vx, dy} = gestureState;
    const {velocityThreshold, directionalOffsetThreshold} = this.swipeConfig;
    return isValidSwipe(vx, velocityThreshold, dy, directionalOffsetThreshold);
  }

  _isValidVerticalSwipe(gestureState) {
    const {vy, dx} = gestureState;
    const {velocityThreshold, directionalOffsetThreshold} = this.swipeConfig;
    return isValidSwipe(vy, velocityThreshold, dx, directionalOffsetThreshold);
  }

  render() {
    return (<View {...this.props} {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}/>);
  }
};

export default GestureRecognizer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, do not edit anything inside node_modules without a package patch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).